# Solve $2^x\cdot 6^{x-2}=5^{2x}\cdot 7^{1-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, fractions

I have to solve this equation, $2^x\cdot 6^{x-2}=5^{2x}\cdot 7^{1-x}$. Now, I started by taking logs on both sides which gives me this funny looking equation

$x\log{2}+(x-2)\log(2\cdot3)=2x\log(\frac{10}{2})+(1-x)\log{7}$

I have been stuck on this step for a while now and can't see how I can go further from here. Is there a way out?

Comment: Your way is right! Now solve the linear equation.

Comment: How do you solve simple equations? Collect the coefficients of $x$ on one side!

Answer (score 3):

It's $$x\ln2+(x-2)\ln6=2x\ln5+(1-x)\ln7,$$ which gives
$$x=\frac{2\ln6+\ln7}{\ln2+\ln6-2\ln5+\ln7}$$ or
$$x=\log_{\frac{84}{25}}252$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2^\color{red}{x}\times6^\color{red}{x}}{6^2}=\frac{(5^2)^\color{red}{x}\times7^1}{7^\color{red}{x}}$$
$$\frac{2^\color{red}{x}\times6^\color{red}{x}\times7^\color{red}{x}}{(5^2)^\color{red}{x}}=7^1\times6^2$$
$$\Big(\frac{2\times6\times7}{25}\Big)^\color{red}{x}=7^1\times6^2$$
so
$$\color{red}{x}=\frac{\ln\Big(7^1\times6^2\Big)}{\ln\Big(\frac{2\times6\times7}{25}\Big)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{matrix}
2^x.6^{x-2} & = & 5^{2x}.7^{1-x} \\ 
\left(\dfrac{2*6*7}{5^2}\right)^x & = & 6^2 * 7 \\ 
\left(\dfrac{84}{25}\right)^x & = & 252 \\ 
x & = & \dfrac{\ln\left(252\right)}{\ln\left(\dfrac{84}{25}\right)}
\end{matrix}$$